# How to pronounce "kidding"

Tags: pronunciation

1. Do you use an alveolar tap or flap when pronouncing the "d"

I.e. does kidding sound like kitting?

Or, is the d pronounced as like a normal "d" as in "kid" (or "dog" or "red" etc.)

2. Is "kidding" pronounced the same by American and British people?

What I mean is - is it pronounced like a Flap d sound or a "plosive" d sound (like Kid + ding)?

Comment: Yes, with a ’d’, not a ’t’.

Comment: Actually, in the US "kidding" and "kitting" (at least as pronounced in the computer salesman's trade) sound *very* similar.  "Kitting" has *slightly* more percussiveness to the double consonants than does "kidding". When spoken quickly ("You've got to be kidding me!") I doubt that most people would notice which word was spoken.

Comment: I don't think ANYONE in the U.S. would suspect you might mean "kitting" when you say, "Are you kidding me!"

Comment: Most of the major online dictionaries provide audio clips of standard pronunciations. Did you try any of them out?

Comment: American English speakers without special phonetic training are not generally able to hear a difference between plosive [d] and the equivalent voiced flap/tap. Both sound like /d/

Comment: @sumelic: At some level, we must hear the difference between them, because otherwise we wouldn't know which sound to make where. But you're right – we confuse them very easily. Probably because there are no minimal pairs (at least I can't think of any).

Comment: @PeterShor: Of course, I meant "be consciously be aware of" rather than meaning to imply that American English speakers are physically incapable of sensing the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Most British speakers differentiate 'kitting' and 'kidding' whilst most US speakers do not. British and American pronunciations of 'kidding', however, can be very similar

British realisations of /d/ in 'kidding' can be a *voiced* alveolar stop* or an alveolar flap (my personal pronunciation varies between the two).  The British (RP) realisation of /t/ in 'kitting' is typically an aspirated *unvoiced* alveolar stop; non-RP variations include an unaspirated a glottal stop with or without an alveolar stop, geminated [t] in some Welsh accents and either a *voiced* alveolar stop or an alveolar flap in some SW English accents (possibly making it homophonous with 'kidding').

My knowledge of US accents is sketchy but, from casual observation, I would say that the typical General American realisation of both /t/ in 'kitting' and /d/ in 'kidding' would be an alveolar flap, making the two words homophonous;  I think this holds true for most US regional accents.  I believe I have also heard some US accents that use (in 'kitted') a  glottal stop with an unvoiced alveolar stop, as in some British regional accents.

Then there's Canadian, Australian, New Zealand, South African, Irish...

*I believe *stop* and *plosive* are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody told you that all Americans pronounce all words exactly alike, they must have been kidding.

The pronunciation with a flap (so it sounds exactly, or almost exactly, like *kitting*) is extremely common in the U.S. But I am sure some Americans pronounce it with a [d].